# CSS Grid: column-placed item going to next row

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve a grid showing position, name, evolution and score of users.

This list is dynamic, meaning **I don't know how many rows I'm gonna have at the end**.

Another constraint is that **I can't change the order of elements in HTML**.

As you can see in the snippet below, when I place items by column number, **`.name` goes to the next row instead of staying on the current one**, and I don't know why...

```css
body {
  background-color: darkslategrey;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  gap: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.name,
.evolution,
.score {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.position {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

.name {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.evolution {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.score {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="position">1st</div>
  <div class="evolution">+2</div>
  <div class="score">85pts</div>
  <div class="name">Jack</div>
  <div class="position">2nd</div>
  <div class="evolution">+3</div>
  <div class="score">82pts</div>
  <div class="name">Kate</div>
  <div class="position">3rd</div>
  <div class="evolution">-2</div>
  <div class="score">80pts</div>
  <div class="name">Sawyer</div>
  <!-- and many more, this list is dynamic -->
</div>
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: I think this is related to the order of your elements. I can't test as I am on mobile but add *Grid-auto-flow :dense* and that might fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid is filling in the order in which you have given it the HTML elements

But you'd like it to fill up any spare space if it can. CSS has the grid-auto-flow property which will make this happen. It'll spot the empty cell on row two and put Jack into it for example.

```css
body {
  background-color: darkslategrey;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  gap: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.name,
.evolution,
.score {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.position {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

.name {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.evolution {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.score {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="position">1st</div>
  <div class="evolution">+2</div>
  <div class="score">85pts</div>
  <div class="name">Jack</div>
  <div class="position">2nd</div>
  <div class="evolution">+3</div>
  <div class="score">82pts</div>
  <div class="name">Kate</div>
  <div class="position">3rd</div>
  <div class="evolution">-2</div>
  <div class="score">80pts</div>
  <div class="name">Sawyer</div>
  <!-- and many more, this list is dynamic -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I naïvely thought that this kind of behavior was automatic, didn't know that I needed a property to achieve that.